# Laravel Nested Eager Loading and select

Tags: laravel, eloquent, eager-loading

When I try nested Eager  loading like this

```
 $journal = Journal::with(['pages','pages.articles'])->select('id','titre','date')->findOrFail($id);
```

This is working but when I try to add select for nested relations to get only specific column like this:

```
 $journal =Journal::with(['pages'=> function ($query) {
        $query->select('id','thumbnail');
    },'pages.articles'=> function ($query) {
        $query->select('id','images','areas');
    }])->findOrFail($id);
```

I get only parent model(`Journal`) with empty `pages`

```
  {
   "id": 3,
   "numero": "2219",
   "titre": "J2219",
   "date": "2018-12-13",
   "created_at": "2019-01-03 10:16:59",
   "updated_at": "2019-01-08 11:04:42",
   "deleted_at": null,
   "pages": []
}
```

Answer (score 9):

i fix it like this

```
$content =Journal::with(['pages:id_journal,id','pages.articles:id_page,titre'])->select('id','titre','date')->findOrFail($id);
```

yes its about  **foreign key**

Answer (score 3):

You forgot to indicate your foreign key:

```
$journal = Journal::with(['pages'=> function ($query) {
        $query->select(['id','journal_id','thumbnail']);
    },'pages.articles'=> function ($query) {
        $query->select(['id','page_id','images','areas']);
    }])->findOrFail($id);
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar issue recently.

With you are eager loading on select columns, it may help to first make sure you have set primary keys on our migrations tables.

Secondly, I was able to get my issue working by also passing the **foreign key** on the relationship you are accessing as a select argument. For example:

```
...

},'pages.articles'=> function ($query) {
    $query->select('id', 'page_id', 'images','areas');

...
```